# How to use multiple dropdowns with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do the following on my site-

When I click on a list item, it must get the text from a span tag with the class value. So that when I click on the button related to that list, it should append the text collected to a link reference.

At the moment, my code only works for the first list item. When I ty to do the same for the next item, it gives me data from the first list item instead.

Here my code-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dropOneValue = "";
  $("ul.which-way").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find('li').toggleClass("open-list");
    $(this).find('open-list').css("display", "block");
  });
  $("li.cadja").on("click", function() {
    dropOneValue = ""
    $($(this).parent().find('.which-init')[0]).html($(this).html());
    handleDropdownOne();
  });
});
window.handleDropdownOne = function() {
  dropOneValue = $($($('.drowpdown-one').find('.which-init')[0]).find('span.value')[0]).text();
  console.log(dropOneValue);
};
handleDropdownOne();
$('a#trip').on("click", function() {
  $(this).attr("href", "https://www.westcoastway.co.za/" + dropOneValue);
});
```

```css
.which-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

ul.which-way {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul.which-way li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.value {
  display: none !important;
}

ul.which-way {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

.value {
  display: none;
}

li.open-list {
  display: block !important;
}

.find {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="which-wrapper">
  <div class="drowpdown-one dropdown">
    <ul class="which-way">
      <li class="which-init">Unguided I-Day Return Trips</li>
      <li data-value="value 2" class="cadja"><span class="value">darling-wine-hops-day-by-which-way</span><span class="real">Darling Wine & Beer Trip</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 3" class="cadja"><span class="value">mamre-werf-khwa-ttu-culture-day-by-which-way-trips</span><span class="real">Culture & Adventure Trip</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 4" class="cadja"><span class="value">cape-west-coast-wildlife-fossil-trip</span><span class="real">Wildlife & Fossils Trip</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" target="__blank" id="trip" class="find">FIND YOUR TRIP</a>
  </div>
  <div class="drowpdown-one dropdown">
    <ul class="which-way">
      <li class="which-init">Guided I-Day Return Trips</li>
      <li data-value="value 2" class="cadja"><span class="value">5-day-west-coast</span><span class="real">5 Day West Coast Explorer</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 3" class="cadja"><span class="value">5-day-namaqua-spring-flower-tour</span><span class="real">5 Day Namaqualand Spring Flower</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" target="__blank" id="tour" class="find">FIND YOUR TRIP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this to get the selected li span text.. I am attaching JSFiddle link here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BXMv6/210/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @madalin answer just make your jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropOneValue = "";
            $("ul.which-way").on("click", function() {
            $(this).find('li').toggleClass("open-list");
            $(this).find('open-list').css("display", "block");
            });
            $("li.cadja").on("click", function(){
                console.log($(this).find('.value').html());
          dropOneValue = $(this).find('.value').html();
           $($(this).parent().find('.which-init')[0]).html($(this).html());
            });  

            $('a#trip').on("click", function(){
                $(this).attr("href", "https://www.westcoastway.co.za/"+dropOneValue);
            });

            $('a#tour').on("click", function(){
                $(this).attr("href", "http://capeytours.co.za/west-coast-tours/"+dropOneValue);
            });
    });
```

I simply added back this code you had in your previous code:

```
$($(this).parent().find('.which-init')[0]).html($(this).html());`
```

Comment: why are you transforming a jquery object into a dom element and back to a jquery object?what value does it have?

Comment: I answered the question based on yours and @Nadj code.

Comment: your answer doesn't reflect the main question asked

Comment: this answer will not work for given link:- http://codepen.io/NadjDev/pen/mmMYym?editors=1111  (Provided by the OP itself under my answer)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the span.value relative to your clicked element then alter the url of the link with the new value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.which-way").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find('li').toggleClass("open-list");
    $(this).find('open-list').css("display", "block");
  });
  $("li.cadja").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.which-init').html($(this).html());
    var dropOneValue = $(this).find('span.value').text();
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.find').attr("href", "https://www.westcoastway.co.za/" + dropOneValue);

    console.log(dropOneValue);
  });
});
```

```css
.which-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

ul.which-way {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul.which-way li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.value {
  display: none !important;
}

ul.which-way {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

.value {
  display: none;
}

li.open-list {
  display: block !important;
}

.find {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="which-wrapper">
  <div class="drowpdown-one dropdown">
    <ul class="which-way">
      <li class="which-init">Unguided I-Day Return Trips</li>
      <li data-value="value 2" class="cadja"><span class="value">darling-wine-hops-day-by-which-way</span><span class="real">Darling Wine & Beer Trip</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 3" class="cadja"><span class="value">mamre-werf-khwa-ttu-culture-day-by-which-way-trips</span><span class="real">Culture & Adventure Trip</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 4" class="cadja"><span class="value">cape-west-coast-wildlife-fossil-trip</span><span class="real">Wildlife & Fossils Trip</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" target="__blank" id="trip" class="find">FIND YOUR TRIP</a>
  </div>
  <div class="drowpdown-one dropdown">
    <ul class="which-way">
      <li class="which-init">Guided I-Day Return Trips</li>
      <li data-value="value 2" class="cadja"><span class="value">5-day-west-coast</span><span class="real">5 Day West Coast Explorer</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 3" class="cadja"><span class="value">5-day-namaqua-spring-flower-tour</span><span class="real">5 Day Namaqualand Spring Flower</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" target="__blank" id="tour" class="find">FIND YOUR TRIP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does work with the edits I made. But if you run my snippet you will see that now when you choose an item from the dropdown, nothing changes in the "placeholder".
http://codepen.io/NadjDev/pen/mmMYym?editors=1111

Comment: @Nadj you removed `$(this).parent().find('.which-init').html($(this).html());` that is why is not working

Comment: Just noticed that after @Wosley Alarico answer. Appreciate the support

Comment: @madalin ivascu....I like your answer and have been looking for it to fit to what I need so I created a codepen with the same code.
Can I have your support on little issue?

Comment: Maybe we can take this to chat quickly.

Comment: fire away your question

Comment: How can I validate it in a way that If nothing is chosen, the link should not take me anywhere and then have a message saying that I must make a selection?

Comment: @Ragmah you bind a click event to the href="#" where you alert that you need to make a selection